# Why are onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) and onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) not displaying any menu?

Tags: android, menu, fragment, menuitem

I have a problem regarding to the menu which is not showing up when I tap on the menu option. Since I have used onPrepareOptionsMenu(), I was expecting that I have dynamically modified the menu content but it didn't show any menu even after I applied the method onOptionsItemSelected(). 
*The code below was actually retrieved from a library to be used in my android project. My project contains fragments while the code in the library in the form of Activity.

Here are the codes:

PedometerFragment.java

```
private static final int MENU_SETTINGS = 8;
private static final int MENU_QUIT = 9;

private static final int MENU_PAUSE = 1;
private static final int MENU_RESUME = 2;
private static final int MENU_RESET = 3;



/* Creates the menu items */
 public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        menu.clear();
        if (mIsRunning) {
            menu.add(0, MENU_PAUSE, 0, R.string.pause)
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause)
            .setShortcut('1', 'p');
        }
        else {
            menu.add(0, MENU_RESUME, 0, R.string.resume)
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play)
            .setShortcut('1', 'p');
        }
        menu.add(0, MENU_RESET, 0, R.string.reset)
        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_close_clear_cancel)
        .setShortcut('2', 'r');
        menu.add(0, MENU_SETTINGS, 0, R.string.settings)
        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_preferences)
        .setShortcut('8', 's')
        .setIntent(new Intent(getActivity(), Settings.class));
        menu.add(0, MENU_QUIT, 0, R.string.quit)
        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_lock_power_off)
        .setShortcut('9', 'q');
    }


/* Handles item selections */
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case MENU_PAUSE:
        unbindStepService();
        stopStepService();
        return true;
    case MENU_RESUME:
        startStepService();
        bindStepService();
        return true;
    case MENU_RESET:
        resetValues(true);
        return true;
    case MENU_QUIT:
        resetValues(false);
        unbindStepService();
        stopStepService();
        mQuitting = true;
        getActivity().finish();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

// TODO: unite all into 1 type of message
private StepService.ICallback mCallback = new StepService.ICallback() {
    public void stepsChanged(int value) {
        mHandler.sendMessage(mHandler.obtainMessage(STEPS_MSG, value, 0));
    }

    public void paceChanged(int value) {
        mHandler.sendMessage(mHandler.obtainMessage(PACE_MSG, value, 0));
    }

    public void distanceChanged(float value) {
        mHandler.sendMessage(mHandler.obtainMessage(DISTANCE_MSG,
                (int) (value * 1000), 0));
    }

    public void speedChanged(float value) {
        mHandler.sendMessage(mHandler.obtainMessage(SPEED_MSG,
                (int) (value * 1000), 0));
    }

    public void caloriesChanged(float value) {
        mHandler.sendMessage(mHandler.obtainMessage(CALORIES_MSG,
                (int) (value), 0));
    }
};

private static final int STEPS_MSG = 1;
private static final int PACE_MSG = 2;
private static final int DISTANCE_MSG = 3;
private static final int SPEED_MSG = 4;
private static final int CALORIES_MSG = 5;

private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
        case STEPS_MSG:
            mStepValue = (int) msg.arg1;
            mStepValueView.setText("" + mStepValue);
            break;
        case PACE_MSG:
            mPaceValue = msg.arg1;
            if (mPaceValue <= 0) {
                mPaceValueView.setText("0");
            } else {
                mPaceValueView.setText("" + (int) mPaceValue);
            }
            break;
        case DISTANCE_MSG:
            mDistanceValue = ((int) msg.arg1) / 1000f;
            if (mDistanceValue <= 0) {
                mDistanceValueView.setText("0");
            } else {
                mDistanceValueView
                        .setText(("" + (mDistanceValue + 0.000001f))
                                .substring(0, 5));
            }
            break;
        case SPEED_MSG:
            mSpeedValue = ((int) msg.arg1) / 1000f;
            if (mSpeedValue <= 0) {
                mSpeedValueView.setText("0");
            } else {
                mSpeedValueView.setText(("" + (mSpeedValue + 0.000001f))
                        .substring(0, 4));
            }
            break;
        case CALORIES_MSG:
            mCaloriesValue = msg.arg1;
            if (mCaloriesValue <= 0) {
                mCaloriesValueView.setText("0");
            } else {
                mCaloriesValueView.setText("" + (int) mCaloriesValue);
            }
            break;
        default:
            super.handleMessage(msg);
        }
    }

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call [setHasOptionMenu(true)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setHasOptionsMenu(boolean)) in the `onCreate` of your Fragment.

> **public void setHasOptionsMenu (boolean hasMenu)** 
>  Report that this fragment would like to participate in populating the options menu
>   by receiving a call to onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu, MenuInflater) and
>   related methods.

Also you should create your option menu in `onCreateOptionMenu`, not in `onPrepareOptionMenu` as you can see in the Android documentation:

> **public void onPrepareOptionsMenu (Menu menu)**
>  Prepare the Screen's standard options menu to be displayed. This is called right
>   before the menu is shown, every time it is shown. You can use this
>   method to efficiently enable/disable items or otherwise dynamically
>   modify the contents.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The menu showed up once i  setHasOptionsMenu(true). I don't understand why should i use onCreateOptionsMenu() instead of  onPrepareOptionsMenu(). I did try using the method onPrepareOptionsMenu() and onCreateOptionsMenu(), the menu did not show up when I used onCreateOptionsMenu() but yes when i used method onPrepareOptionsMenu().

Comment: `onCreateOptionsMenu()` is called once. `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` is called every time the menu opens. For this reason you should create the menu in  `onCreateOptionsMenu()` and enable/disable items in `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` as the Android documentation suggests.